# Update select in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was using SQLite, but now I use SQL Server CE

This query does not work :(

```
SET EstaEnlazado = (SELECT case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end 
                    FROM ArticulosEnlaces
                    WHERE ArticuloLocalID = Articulos.ArticuloID 
                    or ArticuloWebID = Articulos.ArticuloID )
```

which be the alternative?

Sorry for my english and thanks :)

Comment: Is the column EstaEnlazado  part of table Articulos?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing a line, try this:

```
UPDATE Articulos
SET EstaEnlazado = COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 1 
                    FROM ArticulosEnlaces
                    WHERE ArticuloLocalID = Articulos.ArticuloID 
                    or ArticuloWebID = Articulos.ArticuloID ), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Articulos

SET EstaEnlazado = CASE WHEN EXISTS 
                            ( SELECT 1
                              FROM ArticulosEnlaces
                              WHERE ArticuloLocalID = Articulos.ArticuloID 
                              or ArticuloWebID = Articulos.ArticuloID 
                              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                               )
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```